# Can't update source translations in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, localizable.strings, xliff

I'm localising my project but having problems updating translations in my development language (English).

I have a key called "events_title" which originally had an English translation of "events_title" but which I want to change to "Events". I thought I could edit this in my translation management software and import the xliff to Xcode, like any other language, but I am getting this error:

Source string in the xliff "Events" does not match source string in the project "events_title" (Key: "events_title")

I know the string in the project doesn't match the one in the file - I am intentionally trying to update it. Is there a way of getting Xcode to let me update source translations from my xliff? And if not how  else am I supposed to update them?

Thanks so much for any help :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you have trouble with your editor. It should be simple.
Select your file, it called `Localizable.strings`, and change right side of expression:

```swift
"key" = "your localised string";
```

Maybe in your xliff IDE you changed key (not value). Try Poedit app, I am using it and it looks good.

Comment: do you know how the English localizable.strings file is supposed to populate - should it happen automatically when you export/ import? my localizable.strings doesn't actually contain the "events_title" so I can't change it manually. it hasn't been updating as I've added new keys to the project. when export the xliff the xliff has the new keys though. thanks for your help :)

Comment: If you want get keys whole of all app, you shoud't create extensions for localisable strings. If you can, create small empty project with reproduced problem and I can check.

Answer (score 0):

Faced it today, and so far using the following workaround: set/use some "other"/"unused" language as the development language.

With that change, I'm able to manipulate the copy for the "ex-development" language without any limitation, particularly, import .xliff with copy changes, as it's now no different, from perspective of Xcode, from any other non-development language.